# html table with Modal popup

Tags: php, modal-dialog

**UPDATE .....**

I hope any one can solve this problem

when I use `<td>` tag to show my data inside Modal popup the table is shown scatters ...

while when use `<h5>` tag every thing is OK

here is my modal code

```
<div id="myModal<?php echo $row['id'];
            $x = $row['id'];
            ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                <?php 
                  $records = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from trans where id =  $x ");  
                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
                    {
                    ?>                      
                    <!--
                         <td> <?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                         <td> <?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
                         <td> <?php echo $row['invNO']; ?></td>
                         <td> <?php echo $row['income']; ?></td> 
                    --> 
                    
                     <h6>ID : <?php echo $row['id']; ?></h6>
                     <h6>Date : <?php echo $row['date']; ?></h6>
                     <h6>inv No : <?php echo $row['invNO']; ?></h6>
                     <h6>income : <?php echo $row['income']; ?></h6>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: why your modal not working because you are generating dynamic id for each modal and you are placing modal div outside of the loop. Due to this the modal with dynamic id is't properly associated with button that triggers it.

Comment: **Here is fixed** code [https://codeshare.io/VNNkbO](https://codeshare.io/VNNkbO)

Comment: Dev Kraken .. actually your code is worked but the html table had been scattered ... I mean the contents became out of the table not inside table

Comment: Use JavaScript to trigger the modals and populate them with data. this will help ensue a smoother UX and prevent the contents form appearing outside the table.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this issue

```
<div class="table1">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-col"><?php echo $row['date'];?></div>
    <div class="table-col"><?php echo $row['invNO'] ; ?></div>
    <div class="table-col"><?php echo $row['amount']; ?></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
<style>
.table1 {
  display: table;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
  width: auto;
  clear: both;
}

.table-col {
  float: left;
  display: table-column;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td), it states that:

> The <td> may only be used within a <tr> element.

What you're experiencing is likely a browser quirk, where it rearranges your HTML output, and puts your `<td>` elements in a place that you don't expect.

To solve this, you should either replace `<td>` elements with something else (like you have done with the heading tags), or remember to wrap the cells within a `<table />` and `<tr />` tag.

```php
<div class="modal-body">
 <table>
  <?php
   // ...
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
     <td>
      ...
    </tr>
  <?php
   }
  ?>
 </table>
```